# What to group planets, moons, and stars under?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, hypernyms

I am working on a space game, and I need to group the planets, moons, and star objects under a single term. What should I call them? I can't think of anything other than "Space object".

These all have a radius and color.

Comment: (celestial) body?

Comment: @Clare That sounds much better! But is there any single word that could be used? If not, I'll use that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a objective sounding word, consider using 'body' or 'bodies'. Taken from the scientific context ie three body problem. This would make a good general variable name.

If you want something more earth-centric, or human-centric, then the phrase 'celestial body' might also work. Although this is often used to describe all bodies but earth itself, so it may or may not make sense in your context.

Comment: Similar is **heavenly body**, though more recently that's also being used to describe attractive people.

Answer (score 0):

There's the adjective cosmic. However, the (made up) word "Cosmo" seems like something a video game would use to describe celestial objects. For example, "Shoot the Cosmos on the screen." "Each Cosmo gives you a different number of points." Of course, the plural "Cosmos" looks like the word "cosmos", but that's why you capitalize it.

It really depends on the age range/genre of your game. If your game is more casual and for younger players, they would probably prefer a word like "Cosmo" to "body".